# Alternating Algorithm Starting from Center

Tags: php, algorithm

I'm trying to figure out an algorithm to come up with an arrayed result that are equidistant alternating points from the center (can be percent based). So, my end result would be something like:
X = 20 (separation distance based on # of items) - 100 / 5 (5 items spread out over 100%)

- A = 50 (center point)
- B = 70 (A + 20)
- C = 30 (A - 20)
- D = 90 (B + 20)
- E = 10 (C - 20)

Another result would be if we have 10 items (X = 100 / 10):

- A = 50 (center point)
- B = 60 (A + 10)
- C = 40 (A - 10)
- D = 70 (B + 10)
- E = 30 (C - 10)
- F = 80 (D + 10)
- G = 20 (E - 10)
- H = 90 (F + 10)
- I = 10 (G - 10)
- J = 100 (H + 10)

If it's important, I'm trying to arrive at this algorithm using PHP. I'm not much of a Math wiz so I'm not sure if there's a name for this type of calculation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a function like:

```
function getArrayEquidistant($startValue, $step, $nbEntries)
{
    $i = 0;
    $count = 1;
    $final = array();
    $final[] = $startValue;
    while($i < $nbEntries)
    {
        if ($i % 2 == 0)
            $final[] = $startValue + ($count * $step);
        else
        {
            $final[] = $startValue + ($count * $step);
            $count++;
        }

        $i++;
    }

    retun $final;
}
```

Where `$startValue` is the initial value (at index 0), `$step` is the value added or sub at each iteration, and `$nbEntries` the number of entries after the initial value.

As example:

```
print_r(getArrayEquidistant(50, 20, 10));
```

will give you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 50
    [1] => 70
    [2] => 30
    [3] => 90
    [4] => 10
    [5] => 110
    [6] => -10
    [7] => 130
    [8] => -30
    [9] => 150
    [10] => -50
)
```

Comment: This is basically what I have working now. I wasn't sure if there was some magical mathematical way of doing this.

Comment: Although, I'm using 2 counts. $left and $right, and using % 2 to alternate the totals for each

Comment: I don't wrote it, but you can also use a different approach with the step value, and multiply it by -1 at each iteration. (in order to add successively +step and -step).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, this should work:

```
function pointsArray($center, $numPoints) {        
        $arr = array();
        $arr[0] = $center;

        for($i = 1;$i < $numPoints; $i++)
            $arr[$i] = $i%2 == 0 ? $center - ($i-1)*20 : $center + $i*20;

        return $arr;
}
```

Than, you can use the function like this:

```
$PointsArray = pointsArray(50, 5); // {50,70,30,90,10}
```